# Device Token although notifications are disabled?

Tags: notifications, push, device, token

I have a short question:

My App receives notifications, which is great. But I'm curios: When I disable all types of notifications for testing purposes, the debug console of Xcode still tells me my device token.

Is this a normal behavior? Or do I have to tell the App that I have turned off all notification types, so it doesn't ask for a token and therefore doesn't receive notifications anymore?

Information would be much appreciated...

Greetings from Switzerland,

Stephan

Comment: did you figure this out? what happens if i collect 10.000 device tokens and only 2 enable push? I would try to send 10.000 messages from my server to apple each time and only 2 would be delivered?